# Margin of TextBlock differs when used in ListView

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a DataTemplate that displays a TextBlock (and other stuff).
This template is used both for it self in one view and as a ItemTemplate for a ListView on another view.

The problem is that one TextBlock I'm using has some kind of top-margin (or padding) when displayed in the ListView. I've tried resetting margin, padding, line-height and so on with no success.

So I'm looking for a solution. The best would be if it looks the same.. But another solution would be to add a style to the ListView telling that the specific TextBlock would have a minus top-margin.

The DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TemplateName">
    <StackPanel
        Background="White"
        Margin="12, 12, 12, 12">

        <TextBlock
            FontSize="42"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=..., Converter={StaticResource ...}}"
            Text="{Binding ..., Converter={StaticResource ...}, Mode=OneWay}"
            Foreground="{Binding ..., Converter={StaticResource ...}, Mode=OneWay}" />

        ... Other elements

    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If possible, I would like to change the margin of the TextBlock when used in a ListBox.
The following example doesn't work:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, -15, 0, 0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

This is used in a Windows Phone 8.1 "Store app".

Answer (score 0):

I found that the property TextLineBounds fixed this. I'm guessing the value for this is different when used in ListView?

Adding TextLineBounds="Tight" to my TextBlock fixed the problem.